# This code doesn't seem to compile cleanly

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am creating a program in Java for a restaurant. I am using `ArrayList` but for some reason my starter class doesn't seem to run in the main menu.

This is my starter class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Starter
{
    Starter()
    {  
        String[] myList = {"Coffee", "Tea", "Somosas", "Cake"};
        //System.out.println(myList[]);
    }
}
```

This seems to be correct, but when I try to choose from the Main menu it doesn't seem to work.

Main Menu:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Menu
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println("1=Starter");
        System.out.println("2= Main Course");
        System.out.println("3=Desert");

        int a =input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        if(a==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Starter");
            Starter OS1=new Starter();
            System.out.println("Your starter is "+OS1.myList[]);

        }
    else if(a==2)
    {

        System.out.println("Main Course");
        MaiinCourse OMC1=new MaiinCourse();
        System.out.println("Your MainCourse is "+OMC1.MCname);
        System.out.println("The price is "+OMC1.MCprice);
    }

    else if(a==3)
    {
        System.out.println("Desert");
        Deserrt ODS1=new Deserrt();
        System.out.println("Your Desert is "+ODS1.DSname);
        System.out.println("The price is "+ODS1.DSprice);
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("End");
        System.out.println("Program Closing");

       System.exit(1);

    }
}
}
```

The error I get is:

```
'.class' expected System.out.println("Your starter is "+OS1.myList[]);
```

How to fix this?

When I run the main menu it should allow me to choose from the array list.

Comment: `myList` is a local variable inside `Starter`'s constructor. It is not a field.

Comment: (2) missing `}` (s...in Menu class!?)

Comment: Also, did you mean to print `OS1.myList[a]` or something like that? Trying to print `OS1.myList[]` makes no sense

Comment: Don't post links to screenshots. If you want to improve your code, [edit] your question.

Comment: @Shahed i have already edited it, accept my edit and the formatting will be done

Comment: I don't understand @xerx593

Comment: @KleoG How to accept edits. Sorry this is my first time using Stack overflow

Comment: @Shahed no worries, it seems as though you have accepted it already :) its done :)

Comment: @KleoG so is this fixed now the problem. The error ?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger i am compiling it.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger i am using Blue J on Windows. so i click on the compile button

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, I guess this can be solved using debugger, put the breakpoint into your program, and debug.. 
But its obvious- `myList` is  LOCAL variable in the construtor of `Starter` class, so its not accessible this way. You probably wanted to create `Starter` class field with type of `String[]` and then in constructor assign the value into it. 
(btw to avoid direct access, especially out of class, `getters` and `setters` are recommended to use.

Comment: I meant the "parenthesis"(brackets) (all consistent and closing?), @Shahed, but today noted something that won't compile: `System.out.println("Your starter is "+OS1.myList[]);` ..the problem here are the (square) brackets `[]`, you use them (in java) only to declare or initialize arrays, not to reference them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code  won't work because you are trying to give an Array values within you class constructor (Starter constructor in this case). This will lead to a RunTime exception because you cannot create Array constants within a constructor. I much more viable approach would be to create a private  Array as an attribute for each object that you create of type "Starter". Then you can use something that we call a "Getter" method to get the value of the myList attribute for the instance you're creating. Here's a mini example of how we can change your Starter class structure below:

```
public class Starter {


     private String[] myList = {"Coffee", "Tea", "Somola", "Cake"};

     public String[] getterMethod() {
          return this.myList;
     }
}
```

Now we have what is called a "Getter" method in Java which  will return the private class attribute so that users cannot alter the internal state of the Object. Here is an example of how you will call the Array in your main method:

```
public class App {

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{

    System.out.println("1=Starter");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    if(a == 1) {
        System.out.println("Starter");
        Starter OS1 = new Starter();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(OS1.getterMethod()));
      }



    }

 }
```

That is a very simplified version of your code that I simply used to illustrate the broader concept. Here is the output:

```
1=Starter
Enter a number
1
Starter
[Coffee, Tea, Somola, Cake]
```

We simply call the getterMethod() which will return the value for the private Array that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I did few changes to your code. Now it works. Try and see.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu
{
  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    System.out.println("1=Starter");
    System.out.println("2= Main Course");
    System.out.println("3=Desert");

    int a = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    if (a == 1)
    {
      System.out.println("Starter");
      Starter OS1 = new Starter();
      System.out.println("Your starter is " + Arrays.toString(OS1.getMyList()));

    }
  }
}

class Starter
{
  private String[] myList = {"Coffee", "Tea", "Somosas", "Cake"};

  public String[] getMyList()
  {
    return myList;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok that's fine. this is working thanks. Just one thing how to remove the brackets to have one option one by one. and have the user choose one from the starter list

Comment: You mean the brackets in output `Your starter is [Coffee, Tea, Somosas, Cake]`? This is how `Arrays.toString()` represents an array as a `String`. If we want to print `myList` in a different way, we have write it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your myArray is not visible outside the Starter class, so you have to make it visible by declaring as public, or package default. Here you can take help of Arraylist.

So you can change your class as below :

```
    public class Starter {

    // this myList will be visible outside of this class and can be accessed to show menu.
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    Starter() {
        String[] myArray = { "Coffee", "Tea", "Somosas", "Cake" };

        for (String str : myArray) {
            myList.add(str);
        }

        //System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

and kindly update Your Menu.java class as below :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1=Starter");
        System.out.println("2= Main Course");
        System.out.println("3=Desert");

        int a = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        if (a == 1) {
            System.out.println("Starter : ");
            Starter os1 = new Starter();

            for (String str : os1.myList) {
                System.out.print(str + " ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why i get that brackets between coffee and cake. How to remove that?

Comment: if you don't want brackets, then simply iterate the list and print it the way you want using for:each loop or Iterator.

Comment: let me give you the updated Menu class also in the answer.

Comment: i get new error in the new line. I edited the code. New error in else if

Comment: let me give you whole Menu class. run it as it is.

Comment: where is it? i cant seem to find your whole menu class